# How come you can say "I am glad that ...", but you can't say "I am fine that ..."

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, adjectives

For example, you might say

"I am glad that we are having pizza for dinner",

but you wouldn't say

"I am fine that we are having pizza for dinner".

Or you might say

"I am fine with pizza for dinner",

but you wouldn't say

"I am glad with pizza for dinner".

They are both adjectives, right? So it's not a part-of-speech thing.

Comment: this question seems (to me) more relevant to the english or ell stackexchanges than linguistics

Answer (score 4):

This can be explained with *subcategorization features*.

It's pretty clear that words fall into a handful of broad categories that behave in pretty much the same way. For example, there are a lot of properties that all "verbs" share, in terms of where they can be placed in a sentence and what arguments they can (or must) take.

But once you start looking at individual verbs, it becomes clear that they're *not* all the same. To some extent, you can start making some finer-grained categories: intransitive verbs, transitive verbs, ditransitive verbs, ambitransitive verbs. But eventually you start defining new categories for individual words and their idiosyncracies: why can you "give Alice a cake" but can't *"introduce Alice a friend"? They're both ditransitive, right? Do we need two separate "ditransitive verb" categories now?

An easy solution is to say that individual words in the lexicon have a "category", which determines the broad strokes of its behavior, but also "subcategorization features", which determine how that *particular* word can combine with other elements. While "glad" and "fine" are both adjectives (the same category), they have different subcategorization features governing their individual behavior.